# I get an error : Error:(36, 12) java: exception InvalidISBN_EXCEPTION is never thrown in body of corresponding try statement

Tags: java, intellij-idea, exception, jcreator

```
      do {
       try {
            for(int i=c;i<no;i++){

           System.out.println("enter barcode :");
           isbn = input.next();
           System.out.println("yearOfPub :");
           yearOfPub = input.nextInt();}
            loop =false;


       }
       catch (InvalidISBN_EXCEPTION e) {

          // throw  new InvalidISBN_EXCEPTION(isbn);
           System.err.printf(" Error %s", e);
           System.out.println("wrong ISBN");
           loop = true;

       }
   } while(loop);
```

i have class store and class InvalidISBN_EXCEPTION 
and i try to catch this error how i can fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

Unless something in this code (your try block)

```
 for(int i=c;i<no;i++){

       System.out.println("enter barcode :");
       isbn = input.next();
       System.out.println("yearOfPub :");
       yearOfPub = input.nextInt();}
        loop =false;
```

declares that it will throw a checked Exception of type InvalidISBN_EXCEPTION, the compiler will complain. You are saying you can catch that error but nothing ever declares it will throw it. You have to remove the try/catch code around the code.